# Clojure How to build linux executable

Tags: clojure, leiningen

How do you build the clojure into linux or mac executable file?
I can't seem to find the answer after googling.

I have a program src/project_name/core.clj . I wish to compile and build native executable.
Please help

Answer (score 2):

You usually compile it into a jar file and run that on the JVM.

However if you have the clojure cli tools installed which you can do on mac with brew using `brew install clojure`, you can execute .clj files that have shebang at the top like this

```
#! /usr/bin/env clj
(prn "Hello, world")
```

After running `chmod a+x ./helloworld.clj`, I can execute this by running `./helloworld.clj`

This doesn't compile anything though. If you want it compiled the build a jar. If you are running leiningen you can use `lein uberjar` to build a jar file. Then start it with `java -jar <artifact-name>.jar`

Comment: Using graal VM I think it's possible to go from jar files to native code